# Is it a good idea to use a single heatsink for two IC's?

Tags: heatsink, cooling, heat-protection

I am using a 7805 IC along with a diode bridge Br805D (bridge rectifier) IC on a general purpose PCB, with a 220V / 50Hz AC input.

Both the components tend to heat up really quick and I plan to set up a heat sink.

My question is: Is it correct to use a single heat sink / fan combination for both the ICs or should I separate heat sinks for both?

What are the potential concerns I should know about?

Comment: If their pads can be connected to the same point (i.e. GND) then you can connect them to the same heatsink without a need of isolation. Or else you will need an isolator.

Comment: @RohatKılıç Will there not be an issue of heat being transferred to the other IC ?

Comment: Head transfer will depend on the relative temperatures of the two parts and the thermal properties of the heatsink. If one part is significantly hotter then yes, heat will be transferred.

Comment: Heat being transferred between ICs is often a good thing, actually. Keeping two things at the same temperature makes them have more similar characteristics than they would otherwise, which helps with load sharing.

Comment: @Shakti Calculate temperature rise of both components (using power dissipation and Rth(j-a)) under the same conditions. If the difference is too high then yes, there will be a transfer. If you use a heatsink with black anodized coating then the transfer will be less because most of the heat will be absorbed by heatsink itself.

Comment: @RohatKılıç  heatsink with `heatsink with black anodized coating` is a good suggestion I can look into.

Comment: Factors to consider are BDV of insulation, Rth of thermal conductor layer and air flow VELOCITY using a plenum for eddy current air flow at the fin surface not LAMINAR air flow in CFM of the fan. This last part is most critical for optimal MAX temp rise of the junction of 40'C max. Poor designs will be higher. Excellent designs will be 20'C rise in Tjcn .  Fan speed may be regulated by T feedback of a dummy diode or thermistor, and fan fail detect is a must. This was my personal revelation in a contracted design for AVAYA that I did on a 185W 1U closed top unit rack design. Cost was very low.

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 are you saying i should go ahead with the single heat sink and put on a fan with failure detection ?

Comment: uand good electrical insulation and thermal,conduction ... a tradeoff and check surface air speed not CFM . I used plenum and spoiler on intake to suck eddy current air over the hotspots. yours is the fin surface. not easy compromises until you understand.

Comment: you must understand BDV of thin insulator and BDV from PLT to ensure safety.  breakdown voltage, power line transients...and Rth thermal resistance 'C/W

Comment: How does the breakdown voltage affect heating ?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Using a single heatsink is very common - sometimes it can even increase performance (thermal matching of discrete transistors for helping against thermal runaway or better matching).

However, there are a few things to watch out for:

**How big does your heatsink need to be?**

Using multiple parts on a single heatsink could make thermal calculations a bit more tricky. Are all your parts going to be putting out the maximum heat they can during normal operating conditions at the same time?

If not, you don't need as big a heatsink. However, the math on figuring out what size you need can be a bit trickier.

**What about isolation?**

When using multiple devices on a single heatsink, you need to take care that you are not shorting out bits of your circuit. Many packages have metal tabs to connect to heatsinks (such as the TO220 package). However, these metal tabs are often also connected to a certain pin internally. Check your part's datasheet to see how it is connected. Take a look at the following schematic:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fctrkQ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If we were to connect these two parts to the same heatsink, without isolation pads, we would be shorting the input transformer! This is clearly not a good thing. Therefor, we often use either separate heatsinks, or isolation pads. These are pads commonly made out of thin pieces of ceramic (Mica is common) or some other electrically insulating material. Make sure that when you use these pads, you also use the propper screws or protection sleeves for the screws! If you isolate the metal tab, but don't isolate the metal screw, you will just short it out through the screw.

Answer (score 6):

The other answers here are great, however I would also like to add...

**CONSIDER EXPANSION EFFECTS**

When mounting multiple devices to a heat-sink some care is needed to account for the fact that the heat-sink itself is going to expand at a different rate from the PCB substrate which your devices are presumably soldered to.

If that difference is significant it will exert a **LOT of stress** on the legs and solder joints of the devices. **This is particularly detrimental if the devices are surface mount devices** where the mechanical connection is already poor. Best case the joint will fail. Worst, the pad and track will rip out of the board.

These effects can be alleviated somewhat by keeping the parts really close together. Putting them at different ends of the same heat-sink is generally a bad idea.

However, I would still not rely on proximity for SMT parts.

A better solution to mount the devices to the heat-sink using a softer mechanical connection that allows an appropriate amount of slippage between the device and the heat-sink. For example, heat-sink-clamps.

Use a sufficient amount of heat-sink compound to act as a lubricant to ease the slippage while maintaining the appropriate amount of thermal contact.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Very good addition on the expansion. I didn't think about it myself, but the moment I read it I had a "oh ofcourse!" moment.

Answer (score 5):

You can use a single heat sink with two components if

The mounting tabs of both components can be electrically connected, or you explicitly insulate at least one of them.

The total power budget and max temperatures are still met.

Add up the worst case power dissipated by both devices, and see what temperature rise the heat sink will cause.  Make sure the result is acceptable to both components.  If you end up electrically insulating one of them, be sure to take the extra thermal insulation caused by that electrical insulation into account.